# mdm doesn't start X, but startx does

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xorg

I just got a Dell U3415W ultra-wide monitor to replace my dual-monitor system. I am running Linux Mint 17.2 I plugged it in and soon discovered some issues. At startup, it sits an spins for a bit, repeatedly dropping to the console and then blanking the screen. Eventually, I end up with a screen telling me that X failed to start properly. Going through the logs  for both X and MDM doesn't show anything interesting. X appears to start up and then after that it starts shutting down, ultimately doing so successfully.

After MDM drops me to the console, I can launch everything with `startx`, but once I reboot, I get the same behavior.

I'm at my wit's end here. It looks like other people have run into this problem before, but none of the solutions I've tried worked. I tried `mdm-recovery`, but that didn't work either. I enabled verbose logging on X by editing `mdm.conf`, but even that doesn't show me any more information.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out eventually, but not in a way that addresses the root cause. The root cause appears to be issues with DisplayPort. I was connecting the DisplayPort output from my video card (GeForce GTX 970) into the U3415W, apparently this was causing issues. I'm not sure why this is, because it always works after the fact when I explicitly start using `startx`. But MDM seems to think that X didn't start properly.

My solution was to use the HDMI output of the card instead of DisplayPort, which solved my issues. I wish I knew what the actual problem was though, but for the time being this seems to be a satisfactory workaround.